# Google Plus SDK: Sharing videos stored locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to make a UIActivity to share videos (that are **stored locally**) via Google+. For this I had to create a custom UIActivity for the Google+ share button as it's not native for now.

So the code looks really similar to the one from the google api documentation. So the important part is here:

```
- (void)performActivity {
  id <GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
  [shareBuilder setURLToShare:self.url];
  [shareBuilder open];
}
```

And self.url, as it's a local URL so it looks like this: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/video01.mp4"

The problem is that the URL is not being shown in the share dialog that is being opened, and also is not being posted after sharing the post. On the other hand, When the URL is something like "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" the URL shows ok in the share dialog and also in the shared post.

One more thing: When I try share the video via Facebook through the native UIActivity for the Facebook share dialog, the video is being posted ok with no problems.

Does anybody had to face my problem and solved it or know how to manage to share that kind of videos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you try to share video from device local storage. `URL` specified in `SharingBuilder` should be external (e.g. *"http..."*), and you provide `URL` to file (e.g. *"file://..."*). Read about video sharing with activities [here](https://developers.google.com/%2B/domains/posts/attaching-media). Hope it will help.

**Update**:

Sorry, my fault. `ShareBuilder` provide such functionality. To achieve this I use code below.

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:videoDescription];
[shareBuilder attachVideoURL:filePath];
[shareBuilder open];
```

Where `filePath` is `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"funny_video" ofType: @"flv"]]`. *Notice:* you have to add `kGTLAuthScopePlusMe` to your scope before authenticate.